# Banking App With Sensitive Info In Plain Text

Tags: obfuscation

I have a car loan and wanted to make a payment through their website. To enroll for online payments, it asks for the last 4 numbers of my social security number, birth date and account number, but when I type those fields, it's in plain text. Does that mean if I submit the form, the information is not encrypted?

Answer (score 3):

No - the display of information on the screen isn't connected to whether it is encrypted when transmitted to the server.

There should be a padlock icon somewhere in your browser (at the left of the address bar in Chrome) which indicates the connection is secure.  You can click on this to view the details of the site's certificate.